# Google SignIn in Android and IOS with backend server

Tags: google-api, google-signin

I am developing an app in Android and IOS. I want to use the Google Sign In to login in the app.

In Android I use the client ID of the backend server, but in IOS I have to use the IOS app client ID to login.

Is not possible to use the backend server client ID in the IOS app?

Google Documentation

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work on the team at Google: yes, unfortunately, this is a known deficiency and inconsistency of the iOS SDK for Google Sign-In. We're working on some changes and I'll update this answer when this is resolved.

For now, your backend server will have to determine what client the token is coming from and check appropriate audience. Very sorry for the trouble :/

Comment: Did you find a fix for it?

Comment: Can you try something like this:

Comment: [gSignInClients addObject:[[SignInClient alloc]
          initWithName:@"Cross client w/ serverClientID"
              clientID:@"<app-client-id>"
        serverClientID:@"<server-client-id"]];

Comment: Where i have to add this?

Comment: @StevenSoneff - is there any update on this? I've been trying for the past 2 days to implement sign in with Google in my iOS (Swift) app, with a nodejs backend. When printing the response client side of my .get request (passing the token), is basically the google login page source code (??!!), although the user is logged in. I'm using passport-google-oauth2, following the instructions to the letter. For Login with Facebook, I'm also using passport and everything works smoothly. Not sure what's wrong there... Any help would be greatly appreciate, I won't have much hair left tomorrow :D

Comment: @Steven Do you have any update on this? Or do we still need to figure out the client(iOS/android) from which it is coming and then use the appropriate client Id.